# Dynamic Allocation of Memory - this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic

I'm trying to dynamic allocate some memory outside any function (globally) inside a structure. But I got this error

```
struct filaNoua{ 
  string numeClient, numeOperatorDate
  int * tipFier, * diametruFier, * lungimeFier;
  tipFier = (int *) malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
}
```

The error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Comment: You are missing a semicolon.  And you have an assignment statement *inside* of a `struct`.

Comment: You can't just put arbitrary code inside a struct. `tipFier = (int *) malloc(50 * sizeof(int));` needs to be in a function. In this case a constructor for your struct should be used. Although why are you using malloc in a c++ program?

Comment: You are missing a semicolon at the end of the `string` declaration line as well as at the end of the `struct` closing brace.

Comment: You should create a constructor and use `operator new` inside the constructor.  In the destructor, use `delete`.  You may want to create a copy constructor to force code to either copy the pointer or make a copy of the target that `tipFier` points to.  Another option is to use `std::vector` instead of allocating memory.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
  tipFier = (int *) malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
```

is not supported by the language. Such a line needs to be under a member function of the `struct`.

Add a constructor to the `struct` and allocate memory in the constructor's definition.

You also have a missing `;` in the first line under the `struct`.

Syntactic fix to remove the compiler errors:

```
struct filaNoua{ 
  string numeClient, numeOperatorDate; // The missing ;
  int * tipFier, * diametruFier, * lungimeFier;
  filaNoua()
  {
    tipFier = (int *) malloc(50 * sizeof(int));
  }
};
```

However, there are other things you must do:

1. Make sure that the other member variables are initialized properly.
2. Follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)/[Rule of Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) to make sure that resources allocated by the class are deallocated.

Here are other things you should do:

1. It'll be better to use standard containers, such as [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), in stead of managing memory in your own class.
2. It'll be better to separate the declaratations of the member variables for better readability.

```
struct filaNoua{ 
  string numeClient;
  string numeOperatorDate;
  int * tipFier; // Better to use std::vector<int> or std:::array.
  int * diametruFier;
  int * lungimeFier;

  ...
};
```